# Origin of "realm of possibility"

Tags: phrase-origin

What is the earliest known usage of "realm of possibility"?

The term has the *appearance* of coming from a classic text, in that it is a) ubiquitous and b) metaphorical. Without any supporting evidence, I expect most common literary phrases to originate in scripture or poetry. Language users frequently construct the same phrases independently, but this seems less likely when the language is more metaphoric.

In this case, for instance, I find it less likely that many individuals independently analogized "possibility" as a kingdom (or, perhaps, as a ruler), than that one individual employed this metaphor and others followed suit.

**But let me step aside from baseless speculation.**

The earliest usage I've come across is 1826, from Georges-Henri-Victor Collot's *A Journey in North America, Containing a Survey of the Countries Watered by the Mississippi, Ohio, Missouri, and Other Affluing Rivers* (my italics):

> Indeed, when we recall that George Rogers Clark accepted a commission as Major General from France in 1793 and again in 1798; that Wilkinson, afterwards commander-in-chief of the American army, secretly asked Spanish citizenship and promised renunciation of his American allegiance; that Governor Sevier of Franklin, ... Robertson the founder of Cumberland, and Blount, Governor of the Southwest Territory, ... were all willing to accept the rule of another nation sooner than see the navigation of the Mississippi yielded by the American government, we can easily believe that it lay *within the realm of possibility* that another allegiance might have been accepted by the frontiersmen themselves.

A hydrological survey seems an odd origin to a turn of phrase – though it is conceivable it was used here first, and picked up steam much later (<strike>ever trustworthy</strike> [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=realm%20of%20*_NOUN&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) has usage tick up after 1900).

Another possibility is that this phrase really isn't metaphorical at all. While the primary usage of *realm* today still references the sense *governance* in its etymology from Latin *regimen* or Vulgar Latin *regalimen* ([Etymonline](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)), *domain* has perhaps separated farther from its jurisdictional roots.

In the 1820s, seven of the top ten uses of "realm of [noun]" on Ngrams refer directly to a territory (exceptions emboldened):

- realm of England_NOUN
- realm of Scotland_NOUN
- realm of France_NOUN
- realm of Ireland_NOUN
- realm of Great_NOUN
- **realm of nature**_NOUN
- realm of Grecia_LNOUN
- **realm of light**_NOUN
- **realm of night**_NOUN
- realm of Eng_NOUN

Given these three exceptions, I should perhaps broaden my question to ask when *realm* was first used in a non-jurisdictional or non-territorial sense. These three exceptions, though, could still reference sovereignty (even if poetically), as light, night and nature have a cultural history of being ruled by deities. Of course, chance also has such a history, so maybe "realm of possibility" isn't so different.

Once again, I'm cantilevered out on a lot of guesswork. Time to just ask.

**Primary question: when is the first recorded usage of "realm of possibility"?**

**Secondary question: when is the first recorded usage of "realm" in a metaphorical sense?**

Comment: The OED is the best resource to answer questions like this.

Answer (score 2):

The figurative usage of [Realm](https://www.etymonline.com/word/realm) is apparently as old as the term itself:

> Transferred or figurative sense of "sphere of activity; area of power, influence, or operation" is from late 14c. (Etymonline)

Earliest usage of “[realm of possibility](https://books.google.it/books?id=rqFbAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA5-PA5&dq=%22realm%20of%20possibility%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9pKKSzM74AhXYQvEDHTt2Acw4WhDoAXoECAsQAw#v=onepage&q=%22realm%20of%20possibility%22&f=false)” I could find is from mid 19th century:
*The Library of reason. Containing a series of articles from the works of ancient and modern authors* (1851):

> There can be no negatio omnis entitatis we take as a fair realm of possibility out of the power and will statement of primordial condition , and fully of God . Schelling is next introduced to concede that Moses speaks of such a state ...

Answer (score 2):

> When is the first recorded usage of "realm of possibility"?

There are different variations of the phrase:

1. **Realm of possibility**

   The earliest recorded usage I could find was in [*A Journey in North America, Containing a Survey of the Countries ..., Volume 1*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=ouVDAQAAMAAJ&pg=PR20&dq=%22realm+of+possibility%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj7mLOWzs_4AhV4aGwGHZCBCQQQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22realm%20of%20possibility%22&f=false) by Georges-Henri-Victor Collot (**1826**):

   > Indeed, when we recall that George Rogers Clark accepted a commission as Major General from France in 1793 and again in 1798 ; that Wilkinson, afterwards commander-in-chief of the American army, secretly asked Spanish citizenship and promised renunciation of his American allegiance; that Governor Sevier of Franklin, ... Robertson, the founder of Cumberland, and Blount., Governor of the Southwest Territory, ... were all willing to accept the rule of another nation sooner than see the navigation of the Mississippi yielded by the American government, we can easily believe that it lay within the **realm of possibility** that another allegiance might have been accepted by the frontiersmen themselves. [...]"

   This is the same entry as the one you've provided in your question.
2. **Realm of possibilities**

   The earliest recorded usage (available on Google Books) I could find was in [*Romulus: A Tale of Ancient Times, Volume 2*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=D1VFAAAAYAAJ&q=%22realm+of+possibilities%22&dq=%22realm+of+possibilities%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjm-dDSqtD4AhW5l1YBHRZDD6QQ6AF6BAgCEAI)<sup>1</sup> by August Lafontaine (**1799**):

   > (pg. 275)  [...] Romulus returned to Rome with encreaſing love and sorrow. He moved the whole **realm of poſſibilities** to find out means of obtaining poſſeſſion of his Hersilia; but found not one. None of all the Sabinian towns was more hostile to Rome than Antemnæ, whoſe citizens apprehended that the neighbourhood of the new town in time would prove dangerous to their own country. [...]
   >
   > [Snippet view]

   <sup><sup>1</sup> The full text can be found in the [1814 edition](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=vf1BAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA292&dq=realms+of+possibilities&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjS1-eYt9D4AhWMnNgFHecOAqEQ6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=realms%20of%20possibilities&f=false).</sup>
3. **Realms of possibility**

   The earliest recorded usage I could find was in [*The German Museum, Or Monthly Repository of the Literature of ..., Volume 3*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=YGIHAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA489&dq=%22realms+of+possibility%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwizk5bjs9D4AhWDxDgGHTu3AoEQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22realms%20of%20possibility%22&f=false) (**1801**):

   > The human understanding became thereby acquainted with a spacious field of knowledge, till then unknown; the new wonders which it every where discovered, excited its desire of investigation; and as the discoveries which it now made, were immediately attended with essential advantages, it was gradually weaned from the useless reveries of speculation, and directed its activity to real things.—Philosophy, by thus returning from the boundless **realms of possibility** to those of reality, greatly enlarged its dominion, which it now extends to most objects that are connected with man.
4. **Realms of possibilities**

   This variation started appearing after 1890. For example, from [*The New York State Reporter, Volume 42*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=gekaAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA255&dq=%22realms+of+possibilities%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUu5nHuND4AhVVR2wGHd5zBscQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=%22realms%20of%20possibilities%22&f=false) (**1892**):

   > To ascertain the fact whether there has been damage, an excursion into the **realms of possibilities** as to what might have happened, but did not, is not permitted. The inquiry whether the land would have been injured if certain circumstances had not occurred which not only prevented such injury, but enhanced its value, is wholly immaterial.

---

> When is the first recorded usage of "realm" in a metaphorical sense?

From the [OED (second edition, 1989) entry for ***realm***](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00198456):

> **2.** *transf[erred]* and *fig[urative]*
>
> **a.** The kingdom of heaven, or of God.
>
> - **a1340**  Hampole *Psalter* xliv. 3   Þe **reum** of þe whilke is nane endynge.
> - **1380**  *Lay Folks Catech.* (Lamb. MS.) 94   The **Reme** of þis fadyr ys callyd Holy chyrche.
> - **c1450**  tr. *De Imitatione* ii. i. 39   Þe **reume** of god is pes & ioy in þe holi goste.
> - **1526**  *Pilgr. Perf.* (W. de W. 1531) 7   In the whiche there be‥many pleasures in many **realmes**, that we here shall neuer knowe.
> - **1813**  Shelley *Q. Mab* vi. 106   The avenging God! Who‥sits High in heaven's **realm**.
>
> **b.** Any sphere or region. (Sometimes with suggestion of a ruling power.)
>
> - **c1374**  Chaucer *Boeth.* ii. pr. ii. 24 (Camb. MS.)   Thou þat art put in the comune **Realme** of alle, ne desire nat to lyuen by thin oonly propre ryht.
> - **1596**  Spenser *F.Q.* iv. viii. 45   His soule descended downe into the Stygian **reame**.
> - **1757**  Gray *Bard* 72   Proudly riding o'er the azure **realm** In gallant trim.
> - **1784**  Cowper *Task* vi. 579   He that hunts Or harms them there‥Disturbs the economy of Nature's **realm**.
> - **1816**  J. Wilson *City of Plague* i. ii. 309   The **realms** of Hell are gleaming fiery bright.
> - **1856**  Emerson *Eng. Traits, Personal* Wks. (Bohn) II. 132   New means were employed, and new **realms** added to the empire of the muse.
> - **1899**  *Allbutt's Syst. Med.* VI. 626   Loss of sensory and motor power in the **realm** of the nerve affected.
> - **1924**  W. B. Selbie *Psychol. Relig.* 80   Though the term unconscious is used very loosely by Freudians it generally means a ‘**realm**’ where various emotions which have from time to time been repressed, lie hidden.
>
> **c.** The sphere, domain, or province of some quality, state, or other abstract conception.
>
> - **1667**  Milton *P.L.* ii. 133   Thir Legions‥Scout farr and wide into the **Realm** of night.
> - **1682**  Dryden *Mac-Fl*. 6   In prose and verse‥Through all the **realms** of Nonsense absolute.
> - **1725**  Young *Love Fame* vii. 62   A **realm** of death! and on this side the grave!
> - **1781**  Cowper *Hope* 651   The **realms** of Sin, where Riot reels.
> - **1812**  J. Wilson *Isle of Palms* i. 148   Lift thy queen-like diadem O'er these thy **realms** of rest.
> - **1830**  Tennyson *Arab.* Nts. 101   Thro' the garden I was drawn—A **realm** of pleasance.
> - **1873**  Hamerton *Intell. Life* x. ix. 385   The fairest **realms** of fancy.

The first cited entry for each sense (a / b / c) above is the earliest recorded usage (according to this edition of the OED) for that sense.